# jQuery access DOM on https - mixed-content security

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Html:

```
<section id="playing" class="gradient">
<div id="playing-header"> … </div>
<div id="playing-carousel"> … </div>
<div id="playing-info">
    <a id="radio-star" class="" href="radio:star"></a>
    <div id="radio-track-info">
        <h2 id="radio-track"> … </h2>
        <h2 id="radio-artist">
            <a class="outgoing">
  JAY Z
            </a>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="thumb-container"> … </div>
</div>
<div id="loading" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="loading-throbber" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="station-error" style="visibility: hidden;"> … </div>
```

jQuery:

```
alert($('#radio-artist .outgoing').text());
```

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CT95N/

Works on jsfiddle, but not on website. returns empty. what could be the problem? what could i check to call my jquery after dom?

thanks

**Edit:**
$(document).ready(function() { }; is of course already called in the start, so that is not the point.

The problem is that FIREFOX is blocking the content, since I am working on https website and trying to get some data from that site. Since the site doesn't use jQuery I had to append it by myself which means that I am adding http content inside of https website. I think this happens because I am adding jquery external source(appending) from google via greasemonkey script.

This is the warning:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap3JH.png

Can I somehow do this in better way?

Comment: As you say it's working in the fiddle; seems pretty likely you have a typo or a problem loading jQuery on DOM ready.

Comment: is your alert executed after DOM is ready or before it? most likely your elements are not ready when the alert is executed.

Comment: garry can you tell how  can i ch3eck that?

Comment: @JohnMathilda: were you addressing me in your prev comment? any case, where in your code is this alert present? is it before all the div content that you have posted in the question? is it enclosed inside any `$(document).ready(function()...`?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that the document isn't ready yet, you should wait til the doc is loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert($('#radio-artist .outgoing').text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*"what could i check to call my jquery after dom?"*

I assume that means you haven't wrapped this alert with anything. You most likely need to ensure that the function is only called once the document/DOM is ready and rendered. jsfiddle works because they most likely add this wrapping for brevity in your source snippets.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     alert(....);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
alert($('#radio-artist .outgoing').text());
});
```

According to this code the jQuery will called when the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out. When you work with https you have to append jQuery CDN from hTTPS instead of HTTP:

```
    function appendjQuery(){
    var script = document.createElement( "script" );
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
```

Cheers.